# Initializing UITextView in a thread -- Causing issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview, nsthread

When I am trying to execute in a thread:

```
UITextView *aDescriptionView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 50)];
```

I am getting this error:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x2819b0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

What went wrong here? What should I do? I have to have this in a separate thread as it returns me a UIView object.

Comment: The GUI should NEVER be done in a secondary thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must not access UI from any thread besides the main thread. Ever.

Comment: Does this include accessing properties, such as [myTextView text] ?

Comment: I think it is safe if you are only reading info, but I am not sure.